# Print Line By Line

Tags: perl

I've been trying to work on a lyrical bot for my server, but before I started to work on it, I wanted to give it a test so I came up with this script using the Lyrics::Fetcher module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Lyrics::Fetcher;

my ($artist, $song) = ('Coldplay', 'Adventures Of A Lifetime');

my $lyrics = Lyrics::Fetcher->fetch($artist, $song, [qw(LyricWiki AstraWeb)]);

my @lines = split("\n\r", $lyrics);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
        sleep(10);
        print $line;
}
```

This script works fine, it grabs the lyrics and prints it out in a whole(which is not what I'm looking for).

I was hoping to achieve a line by line print of the lyrics every 10 seconds. Help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `split` looks suspicious. In particular the regex `"\n\r"`.  Note, the first argument to [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is always interpreted as a regex regardless of whether you supply a quoted string.

On Unix systems the line ending is typically `"\n"`.  On DOS/Windows it's `"\r\n"` (the reverse of what you have).  On ancient Macs it was `"\r"`.  To match all thre you could do:

```
my @lines = split(/\r\n|\n|\r/, $lyrics);
```

Comment: Or `split /[\r\n]+/` or `split /\R/`

Comment: Yes, the `[\r\n]+` version obviously has different behaviour with regard to blank lines, but that might suit the OP better anyway. I wasn't aware of `\R`.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to enable `autoflush`, otherwise the lines will just be buffered and printed when the buffer is full or when the program terminates

```
STDOUT->autoflush;
```

You can use the regex *generic newline* pattern `\R` to split on *any* line ending, whether your data contains CR, LF, or CR LF. This feature is available only in Perl v5.10 or better

```
my @lines = split /\R/, $lyrics;
```

And you will need to print a newline after each line of lyrics, because the `split` will have removed them

```
print $line, "\n";
```

Comment: Isn't STDOUT to a TTY effectively autoflushed (output on each print) anyway?

Comment: @GrantMcLean: No, only STDERR is autoflushed by default

Comment: I re-read the doc for $| and I think I was using the wrong terminology. It says STDOUT to a TTY will typically be line buffered - which was what I meant. As long as your print ends with `"\n"` it will be output immediately.